# How do you get a bash function to autocomplete as if it were something else?

Tags: git, bash, function, autocomplete, alias

Normal autocompletion for `git checkout` is to perhaps display a list of branches that you can then autocomplete for. What can I do to add the same autocompletion behavior for my function that wraps `git checkout`?

Hypothetically:

```
function git_checkout () {
  git checkout $1
  do_some_custom_other_stuff
}
```

How do I make it so that the `git_checkout` function autocompletes the same as `git checkout`?

Comment: You get to find if there's a specific completion function for `git checkout` and then attach that to your function too. But I think there isn't. I think the git completion function tests the command line being completed so you'll probably need to play with it some and possibly write your own (small) completion function for this. If you write that as a git alias you can (ab)use the default completion function to call your helper function though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you run `complete -p git` you can see what the default completion is for `git` itself.

```
$ complete -p git
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main git
```

The important part here is the `-F __git_wrap__git_main` bit.

If you inspect the `__git_wrap__git_main` function:

```
$ type __git_wrap__git_main
__git_wrap__git_main is a function
__git_wrap__git_main ()
{
    __git_func_wrap __git_main
}
```

You can see that it just calls the `__git_main` function through the `__git_func_wrap` function. (You can inspect that for yourself if you want.)

Looking at the `__git_main` function you see that it tries to look up `_git_XXX` functions based on the command being run and, sure enough, there's a `_git_checkout` function (`type -t _git_checkout` == `function`).

That function provides the completion support for `git checkout`. That's what you want for your custom function. So that's the function you need to have completion use.

You can't call it directly though, remember it expects a bit of setup from the `__git_func_wrap` call that started this all, so you need to wrap it yourself.

Which is exactly what the `__git_wrap__git_main` function that we started with did (for `__git_main`) itself.

So we write a function like that ourselves:

```
__git_wrap_git_checkout() {
    __git_func_wrap _git_checkout
}
```

and then hook it up as the completion function for your function:

```
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap_git_checkout git_checkout
```

and we should be good to go.

---

Implementing this function as a git alias instead of an independent shell function would mean that we could take advantage of the built-in git completion support and **only** provide the `_git_git_checkout` function (the same as our `__git_wrap_git_checkout` function above and named this way for `_git_` + `alias_name` which is what `__git_main` expects) and git would do the calling automatically.